# Is it possible to create multi-select pie chart using jquery

Tags: jquery, charts, pie-chart

I have a pie chart in my project which can be selected by its slice. Is it possible to make it multi-selected? Any links, forum, help!!

Comment: what have youe done ??

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe. That's about as exact as any of us can be given how little you have provided. Is it custom coded or through a library? If a library, which one? Either way, we can't do anything for you without knowing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with fusion charts , I think it is the best solution for your question :[fusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/jquery/)

> Creating a chart involves 4 simple steps:
>
> Download jQuery and FusionCharts Suite XT. Copy the downloaded
>   JavaScript files to the relevant folder in your web application
>
> Include jQuery.min.js, FusionCharts.js and
>   FusionCharts.jQueryPlugin.js in your web page Create a  or a
>   container to hold the chart
>
> Use insertFusionCharts(), appendFusionCharts() or
>   prependFusionCharts() method to create the chart instance, and provide
>   attributes like width, height, data format and data object

Answer (score 0):

With just jquery, no. It's not library for chart. You can use javascript chart/viz libraries like other suggested. Another option is d3js. It's very flexible.

Here's an example with pie chart and legend select:

http://vida.io/documents/gSvr8dAH23eirKQDp